# Not able to set gdb breakpoint

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I work on program with multiple C++ files. I have run the executable through gdb for debugging segmentation fault. Later, `gdb backtrace` provided the list of functions before segmentation fault. Later, I tried to set a break point in a file on a particular line-number. (The path specified is absolute path)

```
(gdb) break /aia/r015/home/sathish/zfs_amr/src/zfslbminterfaced2q9.cpp:100
```

However, gdb gives the following message:

```
No source file named /aia/r015/home/sathish/zfs_amr/src/zfslbminterfaced2q9.cpp.
```

However, this particular does exist in the location. What really the message means?

Comment: Try specifying the source file name without the full path, e.g. (gdb) break zfslbminterfaced2q9.cpp:100

Comment: Another thought: did you compile the program with debug information, i.e. using the -g flag?

Comment: yes the program is compiled with -g3 and -ggdb

Answer (score 2):

> What really the message means?

The message means that GDB does not know about any source file named `/aia/r015/home/sathish/zfs_amr/src/zfslbminterfaced2q9.cpp`.

There are multiple reasons this could be the case:

- The debug info for this file is missing, either because that file is compiled without `-g`, or because the debug info was (possibly inadvertantly) stripped later on,
- There are some symbolic links in the above path, and GDB knows that file by fully-resolved pathname instead,
- The file is actually not linked into the executable at all,
- The file part of a shared library, and symbols for that shared library haven't been loaded yet,
- Etc.

As Pat suggested, setting breakpoint on `zfslbminterfaced2q9.cpp:100` is more likely to work.

If that doesn't work, `info sources` will tell you which files GDB *does* know about.

Update:

> info sources gives blank

This means that the application doesn't have any debug info *at all*.

Usually this happens for one of two reasons:

- You neglected to specify `-g` on the *link* line (some platforms require `-g` both at compile and link time),
- You have a "stray" `-s` somewhere on your link line (which strips the final executable).

Comment: The info sources gives blank information for "Source files for which symbols have been read in:" and "Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:"