# Not able to set breakpoints in gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, breakpoints

My C++ project folder structure is as shown below.

[image]

I am trying to debug the program using gdb in my linux machine. My main function is in g2o.cpp which is inside g2o_cli folder. I am able to put breakpoints in the files in this folder by

```
 break g2o.cpp:<line_number>
```

But I am not able to put breakpoints in the files in other folders, for example, a file optimizer.cpp in the 'core' folder. I tried giving the absolute path from my home directory

```
break ~/HOME/g2o/core/optimizer.cpp:<line_number>
```

but it is giving an error

```
  No source file named ~/HOME/g2o/core/optimizer.cpp
```

I also tried ../../core/optimizer.cpp instead of the absolute path. Still it did not work.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272766/not-able-to-set-gdb-breakpoint). But none of the possible reasons mentioned in the answer is applicable in my case. The file optimizer.cpp is not a shared library and the entire [project](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) was compiled using cmake.

How does gdb take folder paths? How can I give the relative folder path?

Comment: Did you try just `break optimizer.cpp:<line_number>`?

Comment: @tohava yes..i tried that first. It also said the same error.

Comment: You could try adding the folders to your path before running gdb. I know it's just a work around, but might be worth a shot to figure out what is going on.

Comment: If using just the base name did not work ("break optimizer.cpp:NNN"), then my suspicion would be that the file is not linked in, or is not compiled with debug info.

Comment: Does your home directory really have a subdirectory named `HOME`?

Comment: gdb doesn't expand `~`. Use the full pathname, starting with `/`. You can also use `set directories` to set a search path. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html .

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack you can use on x86 is to use  `int3`. Just use the statement `asm volatile ("int 3");` in the code where you want the breakpoint.