# c++ :Using gdb with a large project : breakpoint setting

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm working on a really large project divided in several directories (bin include src) and I'm trying to debug this project with gdb.

My problem comes when I try to set a breakpoint at specific file. Suppose I want to break at a file with the path :

> /home/user/project/src/BundleName/NamespaceName/foo.cpp

I call

```
(gdb) break "/home/user/project/src/BundleName/NamespaceName/foo.cpp":42
```

At this point I get the error :

```
No Source file named /home/user/project/src/BundleName/NamespaceName/foo.cpp
```

I am running make with -g.

I have tried setting the directories with

```
 (gdb) directory "/home/user/project/src/BundleName/NamespaceName/"
```

to no avail.
I am aware of the existence of commands such as "set substitute-path", but I'm not really sure of what arguments I should be passing to it.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044824/not-able-to-set-breakpoints-in-gdb), and no answer was given, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272766/not-able-to-set-gdb-breakpoint), I've already verified all the possible reasons.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I am using clang istead of gcc.

Comment: So what does `info sources`show?

Comment: It's really hard to tell, as I told you before I have a really large project so it shows first all of the boost and other dependencies sources.

Comment: Then you probably need to pipe that to a file and search though it. Also, if you only specify `foo.cpp:42`, what happens?

Comment: If you're debugging on a different machine than the one that built everything (or if the sources have since been moved/relocated) you might need to update the [source path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html)

Comment: The output of `ls -l /home/user/project/src/BundleName/NamespaceName/foo.cpp` please. (Is the file really there, and accessible?) And I don't know about *your* gdb, but when I command mine to `info sources`, I get the output properly paginated, and have no problems seeing my source files in the output. Plus, I get tab-completion on the filename, so you might want to try that...?

Comment: Apparently, the fact that I was compiling with clang was the problem. I need to use lldb.